# Scala Play json parse Either type

Tags: scala, play-json

I am trying to parse a complex json which has different schema for the same field in a same message. So I am trying to parse it via `Either`, but play json doesn't supports `Either` natively. So I tried to write custom reads and write function which has some syntax issue and quite tedious to figure out. Can some one help me with this?

Input json

```
{
   "settings":[
      {
         "active":false,
         "parameter":{
            "x1":0,
            "x2":"Simple"
         },
         "type":"sometype"
      },
      {
         "active":true,
         "parameter":[
            {
               "y1":100,
               "y2":"east",
               "y3":{
                  "blue":true,
                  "green":false
               }
            }
         ],
         "type":"someDifferentType"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried below code which has syntax problem

```
  case class Xparameter(x1: Int, x2: String)
  object Xparameter {
    implicit val format: Format[Xparameter] = Json.format[Xparameter]
  }

  case class Yparameter(y1: Int, y2: String, y3: Color)
  object Yparameter {
    implicit val format: Format[Yparameter] = Json.format[Yparameter]
  }


  case class Color(blue: Boolean, green: Boolean)
  object Color {
    implicit val format: Format[Color] = Json.format[Color]
  }

  case class SettingLeft(
                          active: Boolean,
                          `type`: String,
                          parameter: Xparameter
                        )

  object SettingLeft {
    implicit val format: Format[SettingLeft] = Json.format[SettingLeft]
  }

  case class SettingRight(
                           active: Boolean,
                           `type`: String,
                           parameter: List[Yparameter]
                         )

  object SettingRight {
    implicit val format: Format[SettingRight] = Json.format[SettingRight]
  }

  case class Setting(
                      active: Boolean,
                      `type`: String,
                      parameter: Either[Xparameter, List[Yparameter]]
                    )

  object Setting {
    implicit def apply(active: Boolean,
                       `type`: String,
                       parameter: Xparameter
                      ): Setting = Setting(active,`type`, Left(parameter))

    implicit def apply(active: Boolean,
                       `type`: String,
                       parameter: List[Yparameter]
                      ): Setting = Setting(active,`type`, Right(parameter))


    implicit val format: Format[Setting] = new Format[Setting] {
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Setting] = json
        .validate[SettingLeft]
        .map(SettingLeft.apply) // <-- not sure if its possible to do 
        .orElse(
          json
            .validate[SettingRight]
            .map(SettingRight.apply)
        ) // <--- syntax error

      override def writes(json: Setting): JsValue = json.either match {
        case Left(value) => Json.toJson(value)
        case Right(value) => Json.toJson(value) // <--- syntax error
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What errors do you get with this code?

Comment: search for discriminator in the play-json documentation. based on the value in the type field play-json can choose a different decoder. 

see:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could create e trait for the Parameter itself and then XParameter and YParameter could extend that, then you had case class Setting[T <:  Parameter](..., parameter: T), and for parsing, you could have: `Try(Json.parse(json).as[Setting[YParam]]).orElse(Json.parse(json).as[Setting[XParam]])`